# Objective C program - throwing an exception

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was testing an app on Xcode and I got this error saying that an exception has been thrown. Using the debugger, I added an exception breakpoint which led me to this:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.navigationController.delegate = self;

    int index = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"ChecklistIndex"];
    if (index != -1) {
        Checklist *checklist = [self.dataModel.lists objectAtIndex:index];
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowChecklist" sender:checklist];
    }
}
```

With this being the highlighted line:

```
Checklist *checklist = [self.dataModel.lists objectAtIndex:index];
```

And the debugger said this:

```
-[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array
```

I'm not too sure how to fix this. If any more information is needed let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Uh, what does the error message say????  Did you actually read it??

Comment: As @HotLicks said, it's pretty self-explanatory. The error is telling you are trying to access index 0 of an empty array, if you attempt an access an index in an array that doesn't exist, you will throw an exception.

Comment: probably with `@try {} @catch {}` block...?

Comment: @holex - Try/catch is rarely the answer in Objective-C, especially for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `self.dataModel.lists` property is empty.

You should look at where you actually set that "`.lists`" property or "`dataModel`" property.  One of them is not what you think it is.

Comment: Yep, that sounds right. Turns out because the dataModel property contained no checklists objects in the "lists" array. And this caused the exception. Thanks.